# iReport Design broken when uploaded to the jasper server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I got a problem with report design I created with iReport. On iReport, the design could be previewed perfectly, but when I uploaded it to the jasper server and run the report, the design was totally broken. Here is the report previewed on the iReport :
http://imageshack.com/a/img661/1662/EOrMcn.png

And Here's the report executed on jasper server : 
http://imageshack.com/a/img909/614/wEcaRg.png

Can anyone tell me why It's happened?

Comment: 1 - did you make sure, that images you use in your report are present on jasperserver repository and Image components refer to them (should be something like "repo:/images/image1" instead of "C:\\blah-blah\\image1.jpg")?
2 - Please try view report in 100% scale and check if it renders fine(after completing step 1), also please check if it renders fine in PDF.

Comment: thanks for the response, 

Yes, all of the images had been uploaded to the jasperserver repository. I had no problem with the image, the problems were the pallete's components like ellipse, frame, static text and lines... can you give me the solutions? :)

Comment: did you try the PDF export? is it screwed too ? also what version of JasperServer do you use? can you please also provide a piece of JRXML with ellipse ?